RSA finding D key

Given the RSA public key find the decryption key d and decrypt the ciphertext c=5.
Known information:

n=221, p=17, q=13, e=11
$\phi(n) = (p-1)(q-1) = 16\times 12=192$

Equation for finding d:
$$ed\equiv1 \mod \phi(n)$$

Attempt:
$ed\equiv 1 \mod \phi(n)$
$11d\equiv 1 \mod 192$
$192 = 17 \times 11 + 5$
$11 = 2 \times 5 + 1$
$5 = 2 \times 2 + 1 = gcd$
Reverse:
$1 = 5 - 2 \times 2$
$1 = 5 - 2(11 - 2 \times 5)$
$1 = 5 - 2(11 - 2(5))$
$1 = 5 - 2(11 - 2(192 - 17 \times 11))$
$1 = 5 - 2(11 - 2(192) + 34(11))$
$1 = 5 - 2(11) + 4(192) - 68(11)$
$1 = 5 + 4(192) - 70(11)$

And now I am stuck here. Not sure, what the final step has to be. The correct answer is d=35.

@StéphaneJaouen, thanks a lot. Should I somewhere a long this calculation, substitute an equation for something to put on the left side?

I'm studying your attempts. I'll find

Btw. I am not sure whats your method of calculating the EGCD but $d$ is not 51 but  35. $11\cdot 51 \mod 192 = 177$, $11\cdot 35 \mod 192 = 1$. It must be that $e\cdot d = 1 \mod \phi(n)$ i.e. d is the inverse of e in $\mathbb{Z}^*_{\phi(n)}$

@randomgirl where?

Instead of $5=2\times 2+1$ ,write $5=5\times 1+0$, as @randomgirl said  and $ 1 \neq 5 - 2(11 - 2 \times 5)$ and indication: decrypt$(c)=125$

@StéphaneJaouen you don't have to go all the way to 0.

I know . You divided by $2$ and you had to divide by $5$

@StéphaneJaouen, what? Divide by what?

$\color{green}{192} = 17 \times \color{green}{11} + 5$
$\color{green}{11} = 2 \times \color{green}5 + \boxed1$
$\color{green}5=5\times \boxed1+0$
The last non-null remainder is $1$
Reverse:
$1=11-2.5$
$1=11-2.(192-17.11)$
$=11-2.192-2.(-17).11$
(by the distributive property)
$=1.11+34.11-2.192=35.11-2.192$
So, $$\boxed{35.11-2.192=1}$$
$192\equiv0 \mod 192$. So $35.11-2.192\equiv 35.11-2.0\equiv 35.11 \mod 192$
So, $$\boxed{35.11\equiv 1 \mod 192}$$
Otherwise written, d=35 for the OP exercise and otherwise simply the fact that $35\times11=365=2\times192+1$

To decrypt$(c)$, we have to calculate $5^{35}$
$5.5.5.5\equiv 49\mod 192$
$49^4\equiv 1 \mod 192\implies 49^8\equiv(5^4)^8\equiv 1 \mod 192$
So, $5^{35}\equiv 5^3\mod 192$
$$\boxed{decrcypt(5)=125}$$
Verification :$125^e=125^{11}\equiv 5 \mod 192$

What about: $5 = 2 \times 2 + 1$, I think you forgot that one completely.

See the worked example here(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), if you please, with $1071 = 2 × 462 + 147$

Why this: $\color{red}5=\color{red}5\times \color{red}1+\color{red}0$ over $\color{blue}5=\color{blue}2\times \color{blue}2+\color{blue}1$?

Compare with $147 = 7 × \boxed{21} + 0$ in wikipedia's example.

Can you show what happens before you reach $35(11) - 2(192)$ ?

I have now written: $35(11) - 2(192) = 1$, what do I do with the 1 on the right hand side or left hand side?
